# Can I have Google Now running on Android in a Raspberry Pi?

Tags: android

I have seen some sites which supposedly offers android for Raspberry pi. Are they stable builds? 
Is it possible to have Google Now running in android in Raspberry pi?
If so, how?

Answer (score 3):

No, these Android versions are *not* stable builds. The developers themselves say that they are "barely useable", but several dev builds are available now. Check out: http://androidpi.wikia.com/wiki/Android_Pi_Wiki.

Due to the stability issues, I seriously doubt that you will be able to run Google Now on it. As you sound very interested by the idea, I have posted a few links below which you can check out as the project progresses.

1. [Community Project](http://androidpi.wikia.com/wiki/Android_Pi_Wiki)
2. [Raspberry Pi Android Forums](http://www.raspberrypi.org/phpBB3/viewforum.php?f=73)
3. [Official Raspberry Pi Site](http://www.raspberrypi.org/)
4. [Link to (hopeful) official version of Android](http://www.raspberrypi.org/archives/1700)

If you have any further questions, please post below in the comments

Answer (score 0):

I was researching similar issue, and came to StackExchange to ask similar question. As the question has already been asked I share the information obtained.

Having processed all the threads, posts, wikis I have visited the IRC channel:

```
irc.freenode.net #razdroid
```

> [RazDroid: Android for the Raspberry Pi - Website: www.razdroid.net -
>   Forum: http://goo.gl/NzweV - Status: Android 'works', working on GPU
>   drivers - Official demo by Broadcom (not released yet):
>   http://goo.gl/uStbz - Userland sources: http://goo.gl/EiZ9B - Latest
>   update from Broadcom: http://www.pastebin.ca/2374548 ]

Response from Broadcom:

> Thanks for getting in touch, and apologies for the delay in my
>   response. There is currently no plan to release the Broadcom Android
>   image for 2835. We are working hard to get hardware-accelerated video
>   decode working within at least one web browser under Raspbian
>   (probably Chrome), but do not have a schedule for completing this
>   effort.